# Interactively add shapes to Three.js scene

Tags: three.js

I would like to interactively draw/delete custom shapes (rectangle, circle) using the mouse on a Three.js scene. Can you please let me know if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

There are official examples (at least for cubes) you could use for a base to build upon. Here is the voxel painter which gives the creation/interaction you may be looking for:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_voxelpainter.html